# Table without border after last row and with border before first row

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am migrating a small project from Bootstrap 4 to 5, and I noticed that tables are displayed differently in Bootstrap 5. Now, no border is drawn above the first row (if you don't have a header), but below the last row.

What is the easiest way to get the old behavior back? I use this table in many places. What I would like is a solution that I can apply to all tables without having to copy a lot of code each time. The solution should also work if the table has more or less rows than in the example. I have tried different approaches (for older versions) but have not found anything that exactly brings back the desired behavior. Unfortunately, I am an absolute CSS beginner and use Bootstrap almost only as it comes out of the box.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<main class="py-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">First entry</th>
                                <td>Some content</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Second entry</th>
                                <td>Some content</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Third entry</th>
                                <td>Some content</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result so far (Bootstrap 4.6.2):**
[image: Bootstrap4]

**Result current (Bootstrap 5.2.3):**
[image: Bootstrap5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own custom CSS that overrides the Bootstrap 5 border:

```css
.table > :not(caption) > * > * {
  border-bottom-width: 0px; /* Remove Bootstrap's bottom border */
  border-top-width: 1px; /* Add a top border */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Demo</title>

    <style>
        .table > :not(caption) > * > *
        {
            border-bottom-width: 0px;
            border-top-width: 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<main class="py-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">First entry</th>
                                <td>Some content</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Second entry</th>
                                <td>Some content</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Third entry</th>
                                <td>Some content</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```